# Highlight cells that have invalid data

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

I have a spreadsheet where a user will fill out a form which then outputs onto a google sheet with a timestamp.  This is then concatenated with their name to get an input ID.

I have column A with the input ID and column B with the name of the person who is supposed to be in the columnID.

For example:

```
Column A: 11/11/11Bob Smith

Column B: Bob Smith
```

I would like to highlight any cell in column A that does not contain the contents of column B.  There is a large amount of content in column B that changes on a weekly basis so it would not be worth the time to go through and set conditional formatting for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B:B)))*(A1<>"")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Why not just `=not(REGEXMATCH(A1, B1))` ?

Comment: @Ward because the answer was based on the assumption that does not follow the "same row" logic but rather "from list of possibilities" logic

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditional formatting to a whole range.

If data in column A should contain text of column B *of the same row*, this can be done with:

```
=not(REGEXMATCH(A1, B1))
```

[image]